How often would the season cycle be "reset" if the year was 360 days?
I am learning about ancient calendars relating to the sun, and many used a 360 day calendar. If you did that, without adding "5 extra non-days per year" (or 6 on a leap year), then assuming you started keeping track on the winter solstice, calling it day 1, how long would it take to have a future winter solstice occur on day 1 of the 360 day calendar? How do you figure that out?
I would like to know the general approach as well, so I can also learn how to calculate the same thing for the moon (29.5 day cycle). If you alternated between 29 and 30 days for the lunar month duration (like the Hebrew calendar does), how many years would it take until you ended up with the moon in the same phase on the same solar day of the 360-day year, from when you started measuring? (FYI: In the Hebrew calendar, years 3, 6, 8, 11, 14, 17, and 19 are the long 13-month years. That is different from what I'm asking, which is just about having 29/30 day alternations, when it would repeat).
Note: You can assume what the ancient pre/early-civilization people would have been able to measure, so not up to 365.2422 days, but perhaps 365 or even 365.25 days per year. But also knowing the exact repeat time would be valuable as well. Perhaps there is some equation.

@Masd I don't know, I gave some numbers on day rotation times, so wondering at that level of approximation how to calculate the repeat.

The tropical year is (approximately) 365.2422 days long.  If the calendar year were always 360 days long, it would “lose” 5.2422 days each calendar year, so it would take
$$\frac{365.2422}{5.2422} \approx 69.67$$
calendar years to come back into line with the seasons, or
$$\frac{360}{5.2422} \approx 68.66$$
tropical years for the seasons to come back into line with the calendar.
Rounding this off to $70$ and $69$ we find that $70$ calendar years is $25200$ days, and $69$ tropical years is $25201.7$ days, so they don't quite match up. But that's how long it will take for the calendar to realign with the seasons, which I gather is your question.
For a concrete and practical example, check out the Islamic calendar, which averages around $354.25$  days per calendar year, so makes a complete trip through the seasons in about $\frac{365}{365-354}\approx 33$ years. This year the month of Ramadan started in early spring, on March 12. In 2039 it will begin on September 19.
A calendar with 12 months that alternate 29 and 30 days would have $6\cdot(29+30) =354$ days, and this is essentially the reason the Islamic calendar does usually have $354$ days. A leap day is thrown in once in a while to keep the months in line with the new moons.
